# Bazaar Will not allow Launchpad login

Tags: login, launchpad, bazaar

I am trying to set-up a working environment for application development on my lubuntu 12.04 system using [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/getting-set-up.html) guide.

But upon entering the command `bzr launchpad-login mylaunchpadid`, I am given an error message:

```
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-UpnHjy/pkcs11: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `launchpadlib` the Python library which `bzr` uses to talk to launchpad.net, is expecting to use the `gnome-keyring` API to store the credentials in the keyring, when you log in. It appears you do not have the keyring daemon running on your system, when logged in. You can configure your system so that `gnome-keyring-daemon` gets run on log-in, and the environment variables it sets are part of your session, or you can follow [this handy guide](https://rbtcollins.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/launchpadlib-without-gnome-keyring/), to configure `python-keyring` to use a plain file in your home directory, to store the credentials in.

Comment: I tried this but still get the error, even after rebooting. Although I saw that there was some network activity while issuing this command so it may have worked.